# SSH to drive letter in Windows 2003

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, drive-letter

I have a Windows 2003 server running a SSH server (WRQ Reflection), how would I ssh to it and specify a specific drive letter? (like the D: drive)

ex: from another workstation: ssh meuser1@somewindowsbox-running-ssh-server.com d:

When I do that it fails and I get this error: "exec request failed on channel 0" If I simply SSH to that same windowsbox without trying to specify a drive letter I get a Windows (CMD.EXE) command prompt shell on the C: drive. I can then run any windows command.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`ssh ssh://meuser1@somewindowsbox-running-ssh-server.com/D:/path/to/file` as example for D:\path\to\file physical path.

Newer tried path with spaces, can say nothing

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!

I tried what you suggested: 
ssh ssh://meuser1@somewindowsbox-running-ssh-server.com/D:/

ssh: Could not resolve hostname meuser1@somewindowsbox-running-ssh-server.com/D:/: hostname nor servname provided, or not known"

Comment: @JohnnyG76 - use known to exist hostname for connect (I wrote just fictional URL). Path doesn't correlate to resolver work in any way